# Fiddler proxy settings

Tags: fiddler

Can i set

host 
port 
user
password

for proxy in fiddler and how to set that ?
I am using fiddler to pass web service request .
I need to check proxy authentication is it possible to create Authentication in Fiddler for each request ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to click `Require Proxy Authentication` on Fiddler's Rules menu.